# How to enable SSR/streaming rendering for existing .NET 8 ASP.NET-hosted Blazor WebAssembly project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor

I have an existing ASP.NET-hosted Blazor WASM project written in .NET 7 for which I want to try out the new Razor component rendering options in .NET 8.

I have upgraded the project and dependencies to .NET 8 but I still don't have access to the rendering attributes. I can't figure out what is needed from looking at the new Blazor Web App template either.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated!

Comment: VS Version 17.8.0 Preview 1.0 -> Blazor Web App (new template). Each of the 3 pages have a different render mode.